# My wordPress site only loads when I open Dev Tools/Inspector

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, themes

I have a WordPress website with a portal section. The main website works fine but on the Portal page the preloader doesn't load anything. However, if I navigate to another tab on my browser and then back to the page, it loads. It also only loads if I open the Dev Tools Inspector.

The errors I'm getting are:

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'class_group')
    at HTMLOptGroupElement.<anonymous> (jquery.minimalect.min.js?ver=1.0:6:5819)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.6.1.min.js?ver=3.6.1:2:3003)
    at e.<computed>.each (jquery-3.6.1.min.js?ver=3.6.1:2:1481)
    at i._parseSelect (jquery.minimalect.min.js?ver=1.0:6:5773)
    at i._init (jquery.minimalect.min.js?ver=1.0:6:1747)
    at new i (jquery.minimalect.min.js?ver=1.0:6:215)
    at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (jquery.minimalect.min.js?ver=1.0:6:11349)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.6.1.min.js?ver=3.6.1:2:3003)
    at e.<computed>.each (jquery-3.6.1.min.js?ver=3.6.1:2:1481)
    at e.fn.<computed> [as minimalect] (jquery.minimalect.min.js?ver=1.0:6:11155)
    (index):130 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '1')
    at window.onerror ((index):130:83)
    /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php:1          
    Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()
```

I can't seem to pinpoint if its an ajax problem or a jQuery problem.

I installed the jQuery Migrate plugin but it hasn't helped. I increased the memory in the wp-config.php file to 256M. I changed "this.option.class_group" in the Minimalect js file to "m.option.class_group" as seen on Minimalect Github but nothing is working. I switched my WordPress theme to TwentyTwentyTwo and it works fine so I guess its a theme code problem.

Can you help? Thanks.

Comment: Have your checked your error log yet? If not then have a look and let us know what kind of error/warning messages you're seeing there: [Debugging in WordPress](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/).

Comment: Yes, my error log is mostly PHP Deprecated issues.

Comment: Im still having this problem. Can anyone help?